# How to guarantee injection of a set of alike beans?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I have a bean (`EventSender`) which has a set of injected beans (`Listener`) as follows.
Spring does not seem to inject both Listener beans into the set (sometimes none).
Is there a way to guarantee all beans implementing the interface are injected?

```
public interface Listener {    
   void handleEvent(EventType event)    
}

@Named    
public class EventSender {    
    @Inject    
    Set<Listener> listeners;    

    public void SendEvent (EventType event) {    
        for(Listener listener: listeners){    
            listener.handleEvent(event);    
        }    
    }    
}    

@Named
public class Listener1 implements Listener {
   @Override
   public void handleEvent(EventType event){
       //handle this event
   }
}

@Named
public class Listener2 implements Listener {
   @Override
   public void handleEvent(EventType event){
       //handle this event
   }
}
```

Comment: May be you can use spring `@Autowire` (or `@Required` to make sure that it is injected) and `@Component` annotation. `@Inject` does not gives any guarantee that dependency will be injected

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use @Produce

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({FIELD, METHOD, TYPE})
public @interface ListnerProducer {
}



public class ListenerFactory {

@Produces
@ListnerProducer
public Set<Listner> getListners(){
     //return your listners
}

}
```

then

```
@Inject
@ListnerProducer 
Set<Listner> listeners;
```